# Probability of specific event given two dice

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two dice $D_1$ and $D_2$ and rolled them both. What is the probability of the outcome product of the two dice being $>$ $20$ if the outcome of $D_1$ is  $>$ $3$?

First, I believe that these are independent events, so $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

The probability of $D_1 > 3$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. I am having trouble with the first part. I noticed an interesting pattern and mapped the $D_1$ rolls to the $D_2$ outcome and counted which had a product $> 20$. These outcomes are:
$(4,6), (5,5),(5,6),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6)$ which is $\dfrac{6}{36} = \dfrac{1}{6}$, but $\dfrac{1}{2} \times \dfrac{1}{6}$ isn't an answer choice. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: What are the events $A,B$?   Note:  that the probability of the product being $>20$ is obviously not independent of the first die coming up $>3$.

Comment: You have already used the condition $D_1 \gt 3$ in your working. Multiplication by $\frac{1}{2}$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, you have 6 "successful" outcomes, but the total number of outcomes with $D_1>3$ is $3\times 6=18$, namely $D_1\in \{4,5,6\}$ and $D_2\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, so the probability is 6 over 18, i.e. $\frac{1}{3}$.
In other words: you have to multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ the total number of the events, not the probability of having $D_1\cdot D_2>20$ without the condition $D_1>3$.

---

If you want to use a formula, let $A$ be the event "$D_1>3$" and $B$ the event "$D_1\cdot D_2>20$", then the probability that events $A$ and $B$ both happen equals:

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A) P(B | A) = P(B) P (A | B).$$

You are interested in $P(B | A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$. You calculated $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(A\cap B)=\frac{6}{36}$, and so $P(B | A)=\frac{6}{36}\cdot 2=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: thanks! so I think I got it. Essentially, our d1 role cuts our total outcomes in half to 18. Out of the 18, 6 of the out comes have a product > 20. Thus , our probability is 1/3. Is that correct?

Comment: @hydra-bslash-0 exactly.

Comment: and second part explains the mistake of multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of dividing.